# How to use view in angular js on other page after $location.path?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my app.js

```
var mainApp = angular.module("myapp", ['ngRoute']);
mainApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.

when('/', {
  templateUrl: '/search/login.html'
}).

when('/dashboard', {
  templateUrl: 'admin/index.html'
}).

otherwise({
  redirectTo: '/'
});

}]);

mainApp.controller('logincntrl',function($scope,$location){
$scope.submit=function(){
  var uname=$scope.username;
  var upass=$scope.password;
  if($scope.username=="admin" && $scope.password=="admin"){
     $location.path('/dashboard');
  }
 };
 });`
```

After clicking on submit.It will redirect to dashboad..That is seperate folder with index.But as i have given view on the first page ..my dashboard contain coming on the first page even with styling..how to make seperate view for dashboard page

Answer (score 0):

`You can use <ng-view><ng-view> to have load different`
`partials. You can have a look into this to have an idea`http://codepen.io/dhanrajjay/pen/dOjmxL/

Comment: No.i am asking..Suppose 2 pages are there..1.Login and 2.Dashoboard..I want to use diffrent diffrent layout style for both the pages..Diffrent background diffrent colors..Then how to do..See if we r using ng-view ..we can load content..But what about diffrent style.